# Does an Indonesian need an exit visa from Malaysia or Indonesia for travel to South Korea?

Tags: visas, indonesia, malaysia, indonesian-citizens

I am an Indonesian passport holder with a Malaysian working permit. I am planning to go South Korea for travel in May 2017.

Besides the need to apply for a visa from the Embassy of South Korea, is there any visa I need from Malaysia's Immigration or Indonesia's Immigration?

Comment: In my opinion, the question is just fine here. The OP asks about travelling to South Korea for leisure, so the focus is really on travelling and the fact that they also have a Malaysian work permit, really doesn't make it an expat question.

Comment: Almost certainly not. A visa is permission to visit a country. Most countries don't require you to get permission to leave, or to return from your travels, and you already have permission to be in Malaysia (your work permit) and Indonesia (your citizenship).

Comment: @DavidRicherby care to add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As an Indonesian working in Malaysia, you may be referencing Malaysian law and regulations that affect foreign workers.

Malaysia, with the numbers of foreign workers, has a process of [Leaving the Country Withdrawal](http://www.kwsp.gov.my/portal/documents/10180/179046/leaving_the_country_withdrawal__october_2011_.pdf), either Malaysian citizens, or foreign citizens no longer employed and going home.  As you are going on holiday, this provision does not apply to you.

In some cases, the employer requires that leave must be requested and approved in writing and/or the employer has required that the guest worker surrender their passport and request its return, in order to leave the country. Requesting leave is a norm, retaining a passport, less so. With those items ticked, you simply have to obtain a visa.

As an Indonesian passport holder, you do need a [visa to enter the Republic of Korea](http://mys.mofa.go.kr/english/as/mys/visa/visa/index.jsp).

> However, a visa not required for maximum stay of 30 days for nationals of Indonesia if you are:
>
> - Holding a visa issued by Australia, Canada, USA or New Zealand only if in transit from/to those countries through Korea.
> - Arriving and departing from Jeju (CJU) for tourism purpose.
> - Previously entered Korea at least 4 times within the last 2 years or at least 10 visits in total.
>
> Visa application is made to
>   The Embassy of the Republic of Korea in Malaysia
>   No. 9 & 11, Jalan Nipah, Off Jalan Ampang
>   55000 Kuala Lumpur
>   Tel : (603) 4251-2336
>   Fax : (603) 4252-1425
>
> Submission and inquiry: 08:30-11:30am Monday-Friday, except public holidays
>   Collection: 03:00-04:00pm Monday-Friday, except public holidays
>   Strictly no entry other than the above permitted time.